# git push not working over https (even with a user option)

Tags: git, github

I have created a git repository and trying to push to github. I tried these:

```bash
#1 
git remote add origin https://github.com/userid/reponame.git
git push -u origin master

#2
git remote add origin https://userid@github.com/userid/reponame.git
git push -u origin master
```

It says

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing
  https://github.com/userid/reponame.git/info/refs
```

`git remote -v` shows for above two tries

1. `https://github.com/userid/reponame.git`
2. `https://userid@github.com/userid/reponame.git`

I don't want to use ssh. Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: use `git remote -v` to check if your origin is already added like `origin https://userid@github.com/userid/repo.git (fetch) origin https://userid@github.com/userid/repo.git (push)`

Comment: The error `https://github.com//.git/info/refs` worries me.  The double `//` should be something like  `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git/info/refs`  Are you SURE your remote url (fetch AND push) are correct?  **git remote -vv**

Comment: I have edited with more info. please help

Comment: @iltempo HTTPS for git ***is not read-only***. On GitHub, only HTTP is read-only.

Comment: `-u` ***is not a "user" option*** for `git push`. It's an option to enable the local branch to track the remote-branch that you're pushing to the remote repo.

Comment: thanks everyone. It has started working now with the second optiongit remote add origin https://userid@github.com/userid/reponame.git
git push -u origin master